# Amazon EC2 - Whitelist traffic source IP for port 80 doesn't work

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, http-proxy

I have server instance on Amazon. I have domain which DNS point to Amazon server IP. I have a node.js http proxy (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which is running on port `80` and points to different apps (that run on ports like `8080`, `8081`) on server based on domain in request. Everything worked great.

Now I need to create whitelist of IPs which traffic can reach the server. I've edited security group on AWS in such way:

1. Add custom ip to port `80` (cause all domains point to this port)
2. Left all other ports open from anywhere

[image]

But this doesn't work.. When accessing server by domain (and by ip as well) conncection is time outed. AWS source field accepts IP in CIDR format ONLY like `93.33.40.229/32` maybe that is the problem? Or any other ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you need to open port 80 for access from 0.0.0.0 and close the other ports.  The server doesn't need security group settings in order to talk to itself.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot actually what solved the issue - add server ip to whitelist of 80 port

Comment: Can you provide an accepted answer if you solved your problem?